# What is this? In Florida. Found in plant bed under rosemary tree that gecko' enjoy hiding aloe plants also growing.

Tags: species-identification, species

[image]

Species identification of round soft outer shell

Comment: Could you please add the size/diameter of this object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this a plant or a fungus?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20553/is-this-a-plant-or-a-fungus)

Answer (score 1):

I only know this because I have seen them before in the tropics, but this is probably *Clathrus ruber* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clathrus_ruber)).  So interesting!

EDIT: Also mentioned in these questions [1](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/20553/32892) and [2](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/20553/32892) so perhaps this will get marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Clathrus spp. is a good call but *Clathrus crispus*  is common in Florida. Still an up-vote.